# Issues with deploying and executing EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I am newbie in EJBs. This is my first time dealing with EJBs.

I have two complete applications. The first application is EJB beans deployed on WildFly 8 and the second is a Client app that will use the Beans from the server.

Server application:

```
package com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business;

    // Remote Interface
    @Remote
    public interface SearchFacade {
        List<String> wineSearch(String wineType);
        String wineSearchByCountry();
    }


package com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business;

    // Local Interface
    @Local
    public interface SearchFacadeLocal {
        List<String> wineSearch(String wineType);
        String wineSearchByCountry();
    }
```

Server implementation of the above Interfaces:

```
package com.apress.ejb.chapter02;

    /**
     * Session Bean implementation class SearchFacadeBean
     */
    @Stateless(name="SearchFacade")
    //@LocalBean
    public class SearchFacadeBean implements SearchFacade, SearchFacadeLocal{

        private Map<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        /**
         * Default constructor. 
         */
        public SearchFacadeBean() {
        }

        public List<String> wineSearch(String wineType) {
            List<String> wineList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(wineType.equals("red")){
                wineList.add("Bordeaux");
                wineList.add("Merlot");
                wineList.add("Pinot Noir");
            }else if(wineType.equals("white")){
                wineList.add("Chardonnay");
            }
            return wineList;
        }


        public String wineSearchByCountry() {
            return null;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void initializeCountryWineList(){
            countryMap.put("Australia", "Sauvignon Blanc");
            countryMap.put("Australia", "Grenache");
            countryMap.put("France","Gewurztraminer");
            countryMap.put("France","Bordeaux");
            System.out.println("SearchFacadeBean just CREATED... and country wine list FILLED");
        }

        @PreDestroy
        public void destroyWineList() {
            countryMap.clear();
            System.out.println("SearchFacadeBean is going to be DESTROYED... wine list is EMPTIED");
        }

        @AroundInvoke
        public Object timerLog(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception{
            String beanClassName = ctx.getClass().getName();
            String businessMethodName = ctx.getMethod().getName();
            String target = beanClassName + "." + businessMethodName ;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Invoking: " + target);

            Object ob = null;

            try{
                ob = ctx.proceed();
            }finally{
                System.out.println ("Exiting" + target);
                long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                System.out.println ("Business method" + businessMethodName +
                "in" + beanClassName + "takes" + totalTime + "ms to execute");
            }

            return ob;
        }


    }
```

Server Maven POM:

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>searchFacade</groupId>
  <artifactId>SearchFacadeSessionBean</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ejb</packaging>

  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.ejb.plugin>2.3</version.ejb.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <!-- Define the version of WildFly's Java EE 7 APIs we want to use -->
  <!-- WildFly distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill 
  of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
  of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
  of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0 stack (you can read this as 
  the WildFly stack of the Java EE 7 APIs). You can actually use this stack with 
  any version of WildFly AS that implements Java EE 7, not just WildFly AS 7! -->
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
           <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all</artifactId>
           <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  <!-- Import the EJB 3.1 API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.7 compatibility and activates annotation 
                processors -->

         <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>com/apress/ejb/chapter03/entities/*.java</exclude>
              <exclude>com/apress/ejb/chapter03/services/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <!-- JBoss AS plugin to deploy the application -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.jar</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
           <configuration>
               <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
               <!-- this is false by default -->
               <generateClient>true</generateClient>

           </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The following two bindings shows up in the console when I deploy to WildFly 8:

```
(1)
10:06:22,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named SearchFacade in deployment unit deployment "SearchFacadeSessionBean.jar" are as follows:

    java:global/SearchFacadeSessionBean/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:app/SearchFacadeSessionBean/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:module/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:jboss/exported/SearchFacadeSessionBean/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:global/SearchFacadeSessionBean/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacadeLocal
    java:app/SearchFacadeSessionBean/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacadeLocal
    java:module/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacadeLocal


(2)
6:22,609 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named SearchFacade in deployment unit deployment "SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" are as follows:

    java:global/SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:app/SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:module/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:jboss/exported/SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    java:global/SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacadeLocal
    java:app/SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacadeLocal
    java:module/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacadeLocal
```

To my surprise I don't see the implementation Class **"SearchFacadeBean"** in any of the bindings. It shows only the Interfaces (SearchFacade, SearchFacadeLocal).

Client application:

```
//Client POM

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>sessionBeanClient</groupId>
      <artifactId>SearchFacadeSessionBeanClient</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

          <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

            <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
            <version.wildfly>8.1.0.Final</version.wildfly>
            <version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>1.0.0.Final</version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>

            <!-- other plugin versions -->
            <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
            <version.ejb.plugin>2.3</version.ejb.plugin>

            <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
          </properties>

          <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <!-- Business Interfaces of the server EJB. -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>searchFacade</groupId>
                <artifactId>SearchFacadeSessionBean</artifactId>
                <type>ejb</type>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Import the transaction spec API, we use runtime scope because we aren't 
                using any direct reference to the spec API in our client code -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Import the EJB 3.1 API, we use runtime scope because we aren't using 
                any direct reference to EJB spec API in our client code -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JBoss EJB client API jar. We use runtime scope because the EJB client 
                API isn't directly used in this example. We just need it in our runtime classpath -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-ejb-client</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- client communications with the server use XNIO -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
                <artifactId>xnio-api</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
                <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- The client needs JBoss remoting to access the server -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.remoting</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Remote EJB accesses can be secured -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.sasl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-sasl</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- data serialization for invoking remote EJBs -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>    

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.7 compatibility and activates annotation processors -->
                 <plugin>
                     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                     <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                     <configuration>
                         <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                         <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                     </configuration>
                 </plugin>
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version> 
                    <!-- version>${version.exec.plugin}</version--> 
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <!-- goal>exec</goal-->
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/exec-working-directory</workingDirectory>

                        <mainClass>searchFacadeClient.Client</mainClass>



                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Client classes:

```
package searchFacadeClient;

public class ClientUtility {

        private static Context initialContext;
        private static final String PKG_INTERFACES = "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming";

        public static Context getInitialContext() {
            if (initialContext == null) {
                //Properties properties = new Properties();
                Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
                properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, PKG_INTERFACES);
                try {
                    initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("THERE IS A HUGE RPROBLEM..........");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return initialContext;
        }

    }




package searchFacadeClient;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter wine Type(red/white): ");
        //System.out.println("Enter 's' to EXIT: ");
        String wineName = reader.readLine();
        // Invoke a stateless bean
        try {
            List<String> wines = getWines(wineName);
            for(String wine: wines){
                System.out.println(wine);
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Naming Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getWines(String wineType)throws NamingException{
        SearchFacade searchWines = doLookup();

        return searchWines.wineSearch(wineType);
    }

    private static SearchFacade doLookup() {
        Context context = null;
        SearchFacade bean = null;
        try {
            // 1. Obtaining Context
            context = ClientUtility.getInitialContext();
            // 2. Generate JNDI Lookup name
            String lookupName = getLookupName(); System.out.println("Lookup name: " + lookupName);
            // 3. Lookup and cast
            bean = (SearchFacade) context.lookup(lookupName);


        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bean;
    }


    private static String getLookupName() {
        /*
         * The app name is the EAR name of the deployed EJB without .ear suffix.
         * Since we haven't deployed the application as a .ear, the app name for
         * us will be an empty string
         */
        String appName = "";

        /*
         * The module name is the JAR name of the deployed EJB without the .jar
         * suffix.
         */
        String moduleName = "SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"; 

        /*
         * AS7 allows each deployment to have an (optional) distinct name. This
         * can be an empty string if distinct name is not specified.
         */
        String distinctName = "";

        // The EJB bean implementation class name
        String beanName = "SearchFacadeBean";

        // Fully qualified remote interface name
        final String interfaceName = "com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade";

        // Create a look up string name
        String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName
                + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;

        /*String name = "java:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName
                + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;*/

       // return name;
        return "ejb:SearchFacadeSessionBean/SearchFacade!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade";
    }

}
```

If you look at the last few statements regarding the **"name"** variable, some of them are in comments. When i return the value in the **"name"** variable, I get: **ejb:/SearchFacadeSessionBean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT//SearchFacadeBean!com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade**
which I know is wrong.

There should not be two slashes there, though I think I have given all the correct values to the variables above. So I decided to put the "name" variable in comments and try some of the bidings from the server console. So the results (exceptions) you see below when the client application is run is partly due to the string return from the `"getLookupName()"` function.

When I run the client application to invoke the Beans, I get the following Exception: Enter wine Type(red/white):

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext cannot be cast to com.apress.ejb.chapter02.business.SearchFacade
    at searchFacadeClient.Client.doLookup(Client.java:47)
    at searchFacadeClient.Client.getWines(Client.java:33)
    at searchFacadeClient.Client.main(Client.java:22)
```

**jboss.ejb.client.properties** file is:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
#remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
  remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

The areas I think may be causing problems:

(1) The bindings in the Server console logs don't show anything about the Bean Implementation class.

(2) I think the implementation class don't get deployed to the server

(3) The problems can also come from the SERVER and CLIENT POMs but don't know exactly where, may be missing something.

(4) Another major issue is I tried to deploy the application using the MAVEN_WILDFLY_PLUGIN but I get the following error in the console::

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project SearchFacadeSessionBean: Failed to execute goal deploy. java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection failed: Connection refused: no further information -> [Help 1]
```

So I decided to deploy it using the Server-console view from eClipse by right-click on WildFly and choosing add/remove. I don't know if deploying it in that way is causing the problem.

Comment: That's an oldish version of WildFly you seem to have there; try WildFly 10.0 or 10.1. I don't think http-remoting was implemented in the 8.x series.

Comment: Upgrade to Wildfly 10. The Wildfly quick start has a client-server remote example "ejb-remote" have you taken a look at that. https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/ejb-remote